# Emberjs: Data binding breaks in inner loop

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm having an issue with data from my model not being bound. The category in the first each loop is bound fine. If I make a change to the input box, my model reflects that change.

The problem appears to be in the inner each loop. None of my changes in the inner loop are reflected in the model. If I change the inner loop to be just {{#each descriptions}} and use {{this}} instead of {{description}} my model still doesn't reflect the changes.

```
{{#each amenities}}
{{input type="text" value=category}}
<div><label>{{category}}</label></div>
<ul class="sortable-amenities" style="list-style-type: none;">
{{#each description in descriptions}}
    <li>
        <div>
            <span class="handle glyphicon glyphicon-move pull-left" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-right: 10px;"></span>
            {{input type="text" class="form-control input-amenities" name="amenity-description" placeholder="Amenity" value=description}}
            <button style="padding-top: 3px;" {{action 'removeAmenity' description}}><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style=""></span></button>
        </div>
    </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

{{/each}}

Sample 'amenities' I'm trying to loop through:

```
"amenities": [ { "category": "Featured", "_id": "53dc0aeede4be108724ce46a", "descriptions": [ "Floor Plans", "Pool", "Fitness Centre", "Air Conditioning", "Care Centre", "Pets" ] }, { "category": "Extra Features", "_id": "53dc0aeede4be108724ce469", "descriptions": [ "Three places", "Connections", "Appliances", "Breakfast", "Bright rooms", "Marble Flooring", "Ponds", "All Windows", "Organizers" ] }, { "category": "Community", "_id": "53dc0aeede4be108724ce468", "descriptions": [ "Picnic", "Basketball", "Volleyball", "Playground", "School", "Maintenance", "Customer", "Business" ] } ]
```

Comment: could you post your code in  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ and then post the link here. It would be easier for me to debug!

Comment: http://jsbin.com/yanifonure/1/ was posted in response to my earlier answer. (I deleted my answer as I'd got the wrong end of the stick with the question).